# Connect Points in a 2D Grid

Tags: algorithm

I have a set of points in the 2D space, I want for each point, find the two closest point to that one.

Is there any eficient way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many data structures for optimizing these sorts of queries (which are called *nearest-neighbor searches*).  One common data structure for this question is the **[k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)**, which, assuming that your points are not pathologically distributed, can be used to solve this problem in O(n<sup>3/2</sup>) time, which is better than then O(n<sup>2</sup>) solution you would get from a double for-loop.

Hope this helps!